# Unit test function that enforces specific decimal precision level

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm writing software for counting preferential multi-seat elections. One common requirement is fixed precision. This means that all math operations must be done on values with a fixed specified precision and the result must have the same precision. Fixed precision means a set number of digits after the decimal. Any digits after that are discarded.

So if we assume 5 digits of precision:

```
    42/139
```

becomes:

```
    42.00000/139.00000 = 0.30215
```

I'm having problems writing unit tests for this. So far I've written these two tests for big and small numbers.

```
    public void TestPrecisionBig()
    {
        PRECISION = 5;
        decimal d = Precision(1987.7845263487169386183643876m);
        Assert.That(d == 1987.78452m);
    }

    public void TestPrecisionSmall()
    {
        PRECISION = 5;
        decimal d = Precision(42);
        Assert.That(d == 42.00000m);
    }
```

But it evaluates to 42 == 42.00000m
Not what I want.

How do I test this? I guess I could do a d.ToString, but would that be a good "proper" test?

Edit: I was asked to show my implementation of the Precision method. It's not very elegant, but it works.

```
    public static decimal Precision(decimal d)
    {
        if (d == 0) return 0.00000m;
        decimal output = Math.Round(d, 6);
        string s = output.ToString(CurrentCulture);
        char c = char.Parse(CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);

        if (s.Contains(c))
        {
            output = decimal.Parse(s.Substring(0, s.Length - 1));
            return output;
        }

        s += c;
        for (int i = 0; i <= Constants.PRECISION; i++) s += '0';

        output = decimal.Parse(s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(c) + Constants.PRECISION + 1));
        return output;
    }
```

Now I'll probably see if I can't just set the exponent directly.

Edit 2: New bit-jugling precision method

```
    public static decimal Precision(decimal d)
    {
        if (d == 0) return 0.00000m;

        string exponent = System.Convert.ToString(Constants.PRECISION, 2);
        exponent = exponent.PadLeft(8, '0');
        int positive = Convert.ToInt32("00000000" + exponent + "0000000000000000", 2);
        int negative = Convert.ToInt32("10000000" + exponent + "0000000000000000", 2);

        int preScaler = (int)Math.Pow(10, Constants.PRECISION);
        d *= preScaler;
        d = decimal.Truncate(d);

        int[] bits = decimal.GetBits(d);
        bits[3] = (bits[3] & 0x80000000) == 0 ? positive : negative;
        return new decimal(bits);
    }
```

Comment: What are you testing? The `Precision` method? What should this method do? What is the problem with `42 == 42.00000m`?

Comment: I'm testing the Precision method. It should truncate numbers with too high precision and pad numbers with too low precision. If the method returns 42 it passes, but should fail without the trailing zeros.

Comment: @Tone see [the reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/decimal.cs,134), specifically the parts about bits 16-23 of the `flags` variable.

Comment: Can you show the implementation of the `Precision` method?

Comment: @YacoubMassad added to OP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use this function to determine the precision of a `decimal`:

```
public int GetPrecision(decimal d)
{
    return (Decimal.GetBits(d)[3] >> 16) & 0x000000FF;  // bits 16-23
}
```

So then your test would be something like:

```
public void TestPrecisionSmall()
{
    PRECISION = 5;
    decimal d = Precision(42);
    Assert.That(GetPrecision(d) == PRECISION);  // or >= if that's more appropriate
}
```

Comment: That's all kinds of clever. I would never in a million years thought about messing with the actual bits. After looking at it for an hour I finally think I understand what's going on (I have a much better understanding of decimals in c# now, thanks). So you're basically lifting the exponent out from the binary representation, neat. But I don't understand what the binary add is for?

Comment: @MariusEidem It's not an addition - it's a mask.  It essentially isolates bits 16-23 of the integer by shifting the integer right 16 bits and removing all but the right-most 8.

Comment: Aha, I see. The sign-bit is in there too

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing

```
    public void TestPrecisionSmall()
{
    PRECISION = 5;
    decimal d = Precision(42);
    Assert.AreEqual(decimal.GetBits(d), decimal.GetBits(42.00000m));
}
```